# Stuck in npm install - M1 Mac

Tags: npm-install

I moved to an M1 Mac about a month ago, and I was able to solve most of the compatibility problems but I have this Node project I cannot get it to install.

I'm running node v12.19.1 (npm 7.5.4) using x64. Let me know if I need to provide any other logs, or try any other different command

```
 ~/projects/cybersource | master *2  npm i --verbose                                                                                            
    INT | 16s | 12.19.1 node | 20:45:38
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   '/Users/agustin/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.1/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/Users/agustin/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.1/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'i',
npm verb cli   '--verbose'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@7.5.4
npm info using node@v12.19.1
npm timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:file:/Users/agustin/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.1/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:/Users/agustin/projects/cybersource/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:project Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:file:/Users/agustin/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:file:/Users/agustin/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.1/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load Completed in 8ms
npm verb npm-session 7f6390bbda9e4a7b
npm timing npm:load Completed in 16ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:init Completed in 25ms
npm timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 0ms
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@nestjs%2fcommon 257ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/reflect-metadata 67ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs 57ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@nestjs%2fcore 85ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@nestjs%2fplatform-express 454ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@nestjs%2fswagger 168ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fcrypto-js 311ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fdotenv 136ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fuuid 165ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fxml2js 175ms (from cache)
⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠧ idealTree:cybersource: http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fxml2js 175ms (from cache)
```